# Ordering a List by Last Name

Tags: mysql, sql

If you had a list of names in a table named 'directory' as shown below, how could you write a query that returns these names but displays them in alphabetical order by last name

directory:

```
Jason Howard, Tom Albert, Sam Smith
```

To do this by first name, I would think you can just do:

```
select * from directory order by name
```

I'm assuming the full name is the field 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a note.  There is no reason to select the last name in order to order by it.  You can just use the expression in the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1)
```

`TRIM()` should not be necessary unless your data is really sloppy -- with spaces at the end of the name column.

Answer (score 1):

As jim horn said, it's not a good approach. But if we consider the last part of the name as the last name of users (which of course, separated by spaces), then you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(name), ' ', -1) AS LAST_NAME FROM `table_name` ORDER BY LAST_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks - quick question - what is not a good approach? To list the 2 names in 1 column?

Comment: Yes, When you want query on a field, Try to have it in a separated column.

Comment: @user2603139 you should have separate columns for first and last names, and probably middle names/initials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does your table only have the full name with firstname space lastname, or separate columns for first and last name?

If yes, then it's your query with ORDER BY lastname.

If no, then what you're asking is going to be a real pain to code for those with multiple spaces in their name, as you'll never get the logic down for which one is the last name, such as Jean Claude Van Damme, Phil Vander Beek, Hong Kong Phooey, and Bill S. Preston Esquire III.

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of this example, just assume everyone has 1 first name and 1 last name and this is all part of the same column referred to as name (although if anyone can also provide a generalized solution for the example you've suggested where the number of names - i.e. first, middle, last - is unknown that would be interesting

Comment: @user2603139 you can't make a generalised solution as there's no way to distinguish between someone with a multi-word last name and someone who has  middle names. e.g. Rip van Winkle, John Paul Smith

Comment: OK - is there a way to do this using "Case" such as from: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-if-then-logic-in-sql-server/

I would imagine there is a solution using this